# Disk read speed discrepancy in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hdfs

I'm testing how much time I need to load a table stored in HDFS using Spark (I'm using a JavaHiveContext).

My table is 22,4Gb and is split in 215 block, so when I read it I got 215 task.

From results each task read at a speed of 42Mb/sec (2,54 sec to read 107Mb each task) (in my test I use 1 executor with one core) but on my host the disk speed is not less than 100Mb/sec.

Why I get this discrepancy?

Comment: *"disk speed is not less than 100Mb/sec"* >>> you mean that **in theory**, a **single** task doing **sequential** reads on a **single** disk should reach 100 MB/s **after warmup**?